# Getting F# working in VSCode when "dotnet" is not found on MacOSX?

Tags: macos, .net-core, visual-studio-code, f#, ionide

I'm completely new to dotnet and vscode so I might be missing something trivial. I just want to get F# running in VSCode on my Mac. I first tried installing dotnet from brew:

```
brew cask install dotnet-sdk
```

This seems to be working fine from the command line since I could do both `dotnet new` and `dotnet build`:

```
dotnet new console -lang F# -o myproj
```

Now I installed Visual Studio Code, also from brew:

```
brew cask install visual-studio-code
```

I then installed the [Ionide-fsharp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ionide.Ionide-fsharp) plugin, opened the `myproj` folder from vscode and restarted it. I'm then greeted with:

[image: error]

I then searched for `FSharp.dotnetRoot` in the settings and tried to configure this:

[image]

But it didn't help (I also tried setting the folder to `/usr/local/share/dotnet` and `/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100` but nothing worked).

So I completely uninstalled everything (including wiping my `~/.vscode` folder) from brew and re-installed everything from the official [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/install-fsharp). In the docs it says that the F# support should be built-in to vscode on macosx, but it still recommended me to install Ionide-fsharp when I opened the folder again, so I obeyed. But I just ran into exactly the same problem again.

So my question is: How can I install vscode with working F# support on MacOSX?

Here's my output from vscode "about":

```
Version: 1.41.0
Commit: 9579eda04fdb3a9bba2750f15193e5fafe16b959
Date: 2019-12-11T17:58:38.338Z
Electron: 6.1.5
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.2.0
```

and this is from `dotnet --info`:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.100
 Commit:    cd82f021f4

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.15
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.15-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.0
  Commit:  65f04fb6db

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: Did you restart vscode after setting the dotnetRoot property? It doesn't say so on the settings description, bit it requires a restart of VS Code to take effect.

Comment: Yes I restarted, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Can you post an issue to the ionide repo with a link here or the contents of this message? I and the other maintainers might be able to get more info there.

Comment: I posted an issue here: https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp/issues/1271

Comment: It's been a while so apologies if these are wrong, but some things to try: (1) Install using the instructions at dotnet.microsoft.com rather than using brew. (2) Add the dotnet SDK location to your PATH environment variable with `sudo nano /etc/paths` (3) Create symlink with `ln -s /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/` (you may need to modify the paths slightly for your case).